# Nested component list does not update correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a recursively defined component tree which is something like this:

```
class MyListItem extends Component {

 ...

 componentDidMount() {

   this.listener = dataUpdateEvent.addListener(event, (newState) => {
     if(newState.id == this.state.id) {
       this.setState(newState)
     }  
   })     

 }

 ...

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
       <div>
       {this.state.children.map( child => {
         return (<MyListItem key={child.id} data={child} />)
       })}
       </div>
     </div>
   )
 }

}
```

So basically this view renders a series of nested lists to represent a tree-like data structure.  `dataUpdateEvent` is triggered various ways, and *is intended to* trigger a reload of the relevant component, and all sub-lists.

However I'm running into some strange behavior.  Specifically, if one `MyListItem` component and its child update in quick succession, I see the top level list change as expected, but the sub-list remains in an un-altered state.

Interestingly, if I use randomized keys for the list items, everything works perfectly:

```
...
return (<MyListItem key={uuid()} data={child} />)
...
```

Although there is some undesirable UI lag.  My thought is, maybe there is something to do with key-based caching that causes this issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

React uses the keys to map changes so you need those. There should be a warning in the console if you don't use unique keys. Do you have any duplicate ids? Also try passing all your data in as props instead of setting state, then you won't need a listener at all.

Comment: Nope, I'm quite sure they are unique.  They are UUIDs generated by the server.

Comment: should it be if(newState.id != this.state.id) { so it updates when a new id is passed in?

Comment: does your listener ever fire. put a console.log in there to check if it fires

Comment: consider using ComponentDidUpdate instead of ComponentDidMount

Comment: `newState.id == this.state.id` is correct.  It's basically filtering all events only for the relevant key.

Comment: probably need more code to go on, might be an issue in the format of the data in the parent component

Comment: ok I will try to put together a gist when i have time.  It's part of a larger product, so it's not totally straight-forward to extract the relevant part.

Comment: can you pass the data in as props instead of setting state?